# How to use a variable in place of a method when calling a class?

Tags: python, class, variables, methods

Let's say I have a function `func` in `main.py`, and a class `Tree` in `mod.py`. `Tree` has methods `apple()`, `orange()`, and `banana()`. This is `main.py`:

```py
from . import mod

def func(arg, meth):
    tree = mod.Tree
    tree.meth(arg)
```

`func` is *supposed* to call a method from `Tree` from the `meth` argument, but instead tries to find a `meth` attribute. Instead of it trying to find an attribute, how would you replace that with a variable?

Comment: Can you show how you intend to call this function? What exactly do you pass as `meth`?

Comment: One of the methods; `apple()`, `orange()`, or `banana()`

Comment: Can you share the `Tree` class? Are the methods `classmethod`s? You can probably get the method using `getattr`: `getattr(tree, meth)(arg)`

Comment: Shouldn't you have instantiated a `Tree` instance (i.e. `tree = mod.Tree()`)? Or are you trying to access a static method / class method from `Tree`? Additionally, what data type is `meth`?

Comment: @jfaccioni It doesn't matter if you instantiate it or not because you're just calling the method, which in that case kinda defeats the purpose of the class, and now that I think about it, I probably could've just done `from mod import *`...

Comment: It definitely does matter - calling an instance method as `Tree.meth(arg)` (i.e. on the class) instead of `Tree().meth(arg)` (i.e. on an instance of the class) results in a `TypeError`, because in the first case you're not passing in the instance as the first argument to the method (tipically named `self`).

Comment: Huh, so why doesn't the same happen when you do something like `import x as y` and then `y.z(arg)`?

Comment: Oops, I meant `from x import y`

Edit: Nevermind I was thinking of PIL when I wrote that comment, and PIL is a folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `getattr()`

```
def func(arg, meth):
    tree = mod.Tree
    getattr(tree, meth)(arg)
```

This accesses the attribute (property or function) of the object (`tree`) named by the variable (`meth`) specified. Then you have the function and you can call it.

Comment: Ah okay, I was confused about that method because I thought it just assigned an attribute to a variable. `=` can already do that so I guess it wouldn't make sense to have it if it did do that.

Comment: @Shidouuu if you wanted to do setting an attribute dynamically `setattr()`